# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then' in if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im having an issue while running this query its showing "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'" and the datatype of CorrectAnswer and AnswerID are varchar(10).

```
   select  T.[AssociateID],  
           T.[QuestionID],  
           T.[Result]  
   from
        AssociateAssessmentTransaction T  
        left join   
        AssessmentQuestions A  
        on  T.[QuestionID]=T.[QuestionID]  
        group by T.[AssociateID],
                 T.[QuestionID],
                 T.[Result]
        if(A.[CorrectAnswer] = T.[AnswerID]) 
          then 
          T.[Result] = 1;
        else  
          T.[Result] = 0;
        end if
```

Answer (score 7):

You can not Use `if then` like this in your Statement

You should use like this

```
   select  T.[AssociateID],  
           T.[QuestionID],  
           case when A.[CorrectAnswer] = T.[AnswerID] 
           then 1 else 0 end as Result
   from
        AssociateAssessmentTransaction T  
        left join   
        AssessmentQuestions A  
        on  T.[QuestionID]=T.[QuestionID]  
        group by T.[AssociateID],
                 T.[QuestionID],
                 T.[Result]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no if else comes in select query, you can use case statment

```
select  T.[AssociateID],  
           T.[QuestionID],  
           T.[Result]  
   from
        AssociateAssessmentTransaction T  
        left join   
        AssessmentQuestions A  
        on  T.[QuestionID]=T.[QuestionID]  
        and T.[Result] =
            case when (A.[CorrectAnswer] = T.[AnswerID]) 
               then 1;
            else  0;
          end

        group by T.[AssociateID],
                 T.[QuestionID],
                 T.[Result]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are searching for **case when**

```
    select  T.[AssociateID],  
               T.[QuestionID],  
               T.[Result]  ,
  case when A.[CorrectAnswer] = T.[AnswerID]
              then 
              T.[Result] = 1;
            else  
              T.[Result] = 0;
            end as Result
       from
            AssociateAssessmentTransaction T  
            left join   
            AssessmentQuestions A  
            on  T.[QuestionID]=T.[QuestionID]  
            group by T.[AssociateID],
                     T.[QuestionID],
                     T.[Result]
```

Comment: thnx alot guys for ur help,The problem has been taken care now